# how to get the value corresponding to the position of the mouse cursor on the curve now?

Tags: delphi, teechart

How to get the value corresponding to the position of the mouse cursor on the curve now?

I tried GetHorizAxis.LabelValue, but it just get the value where the mouse position is.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `XScreenToValue` for needed `Series` to convert coordinate into the value at the corresponding axis:

```
procedure TForm1.Chart1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  Caption := FloatToStr(Series1.XScreenToValue(X));
end;
```

Comment: thanks.i found a TDBChart tool named : Mark Tips.   this is work for me.